# how to setup JPA project to work with Hibernate?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

I'm having trouble setting up a project in Eclipse that uses pure JPA mechanisms but with Hibernate as the implementation layer.

I have a simple program with 2 classes linked by a many-to-many relationship all defined using annotations.

I would like to avoid using hibernate specific configuration in order to stay as independent as possible from the database. For instance I'd like all my configuration to be in the persistence.xml file.

Each time I start the program I have the following error :

```
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Test-Cache-Hibernate
    ...]
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
juil. 18, 2014 7:28:11 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
```

context :
 Eclipse Luna
 JPA 2.1
 Hibernate 4.3.5

here is my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Test-Cache-Hibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>datasource</non-jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testcache"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have isolated the creation of the entity manager in a Singleton class that is as follows :

```
package src.persistence.dbmanager;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class DBManager {

    public static final EntityManager entityManager;

    static {
        try {
            entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test-Cache-Hibernate").createEntityManager();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

I have the error mentionned above when I manually inject the EntityManager in the DAO objects using :

```
private EntityManager entityManager = DBManager.getEntityManager();
```

Edit 1 :
Here the code of one of my DAO object :

```
package acs.testcache.persistence.dao;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import acs.testcache.persistence.entities.MyChildObject;
import acs.testcache.persistence.entities.MyParentObject;


public class MyChildDAO extends MyCommonDAO<MyChildObject> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="Test-Cache-Hibernate")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyChildDAO() {
        super(MyChildObject.class);
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void getParents(MyChildObject c){

        StringBuilder hqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
        hqlQuery.append("select c.parentsObjects from MyChildObject c where c.id = :id");

        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(hqlQuery.toString()).setParameter("id", c.getId()).setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
        List<MyParentObject> result = q.getResultList();

        c.setParents(new HashSet<MyParentObject>(result));
    }
}
```

The persistence manager is never injected.

when I try using the annotation to automatically inject it I have a null pointer exception when querying.

Can anybody help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you resolved it since ?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the code for how you inject the `EntityManager` using annotations.  Have you tried using `@PersistenceContext` annotation like so?

> @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

Using `@Component`, `@Resource` (or whatever Java's native equivalent annotation is) will not work in this case.

Comment: thank for your answer. See my Edit 1. I tried using the `@PersistenceContext` to no avail, the entity manager is never injected. I finally was able to have this running by just removing the `<non-jta-datasource>` tag from the persistence.xml, but I don't understand why it suddenly works and therefore is not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `persistence.xml` I cannot see any declaration of entities. You should define entity classes here. Something like `<class>com.example.package.TestEntity<class>`.

Also in your `DBManager` you should specify what are your resources and EntityManger. Use DI, something like: 
`@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Test-Cache-Hibernate")`
`private EntityManager em;`

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with missing entities.

Comment: @JamesB True. But it will be his next problem. I addressed two issues that I saw in the code. missing entities was one of them.

Comment: @JamesB thanks for the tip, but my understanding was that the entities annotated with `@Entity` were automatically detected. Am I wrong ? concerning the `@PersistenceContext` please see my Edit 1, and this does not work properly. The only way I have an entity manager is by explicitely calling `private EntityManager entityManager = DBManager.getEntityManager();`

Comment: @Marco entity detecting is automatic if you defined the class of the entities in `persistence.xml` otherwise you will end up with Unknown Entity Exception (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity ...`)